# React Native instant render

Tags: android, react-native, reactive-programming

I am new to react native. I am using Atom IDE for developing the Android application. I have small doubt reading react. while designing the component in the react native is there any way for instant render window.

Comment: Are you talking about HMR (Hot Module Reload)? Enable it from the dev menu (with `adb shell input keyevent 82`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use "**Enable Hot reloading**" feature of react native to instant render on your real device or emulator.

To enable this feature once you run your application in real device then shake your device then you will get following screen: choose Enable hot reloading option. Once you save your file it will immediately reflect

[image]

If you are using android emulator then use following option

1. press R two times to reload
2. press ***Ctrl + M*** open dev shake menu in emulator

There are other option in dev menu which is useful are:

1. Debug JS Remotely: This option is helpful to debug your application in chrome browser. It is similar to web development dev tools to debug. Whenever you add any console.log or console.warn statement in your code it will print in dev tool under console tab.
2. Dev Settings: Here you can give your IPV4 address to connect with your real device to system. To identify IPV4 address you can use **ipconfig** command in your CMD.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Enable Live Reload" also.